# JSDoc for dynamic attached properties (VSCode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a constructor for a class that adds dynamic properties based on a parameter:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(attach) {
        for (const key in attach) {
            this[key] = attach[key];
        }
    }
}

class Bar {
    getBar() { return "bar"; }
}


const foo = new Foo({
    bar: new Bar()
})

console.log(foo.bar.getBar());
```

The properties are just a shorthand for the properties which are injected.

I wanted to document Foo somehow so that callsites can get decent autocompletion.

I tried some variations of the code below, but VSCode still can't find the properties of T in the instance of Foo:

```
/**
 * Foogler
 * @template {{[key:string]: Bar}} T
 * @type {Foo & T}
 */
class Foo {
    /**
     * Creates a new Foo
     * @param {T} attach
     */
    constructor(attach) {
```